# KendoUI Chart Zoom on a date axis

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, linechart

I have a KendoUI line chart with a date field on the x-axis.  I would like to initially plot months but when the user zooms that it zooms into weeks, days, hours etc. so that the user can drill all the way to a time period.

It seems to work fine when using a Stock chart however I cannot get it to work using a regular line chart:

I think the core of the issue is setting the Category axis values correctly, my values are:

```
              categoryAxis: {
                  baseUnit: "fit",

                  // Constraint number of groups to 5
                  maxDateGroups: 5,

                  autoBaseUnitSteps: {
                      days: [1],

                      weeks: [],

                      months: [3]
                  }
                }
```

Link below:
http://dojo.telerik.com/EJuMe

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?